# How can I filter which children I want to show in a sub navigation menu

Tags: navigation, descendantof

I have a navigation menu setup but I want to filter out some of the children at level(2) so they aren't showing in the dropdown navigation menu. Here is how I am grabbing the children...

```
{% set mainEntry = craft.entries.slug(craft.request.getSegment(1)).one() %}
{% set subnav = craft.entries.descendantOf(mainEntry).level(2) %}

<div class="menu">
            <ul class="no-list-style">
                <li><a href="{{mainEntry.getUrl}}">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Conference</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                        <ul class="no-list-style">
                            {% for page in subnav %}
                            <li>
                                {{ page.link }} 
                            </li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
             </ul>
          </div>
```

Comment: Can you add more details on the filtering? Are you just needing to manually pick entries to hide from the nav?

Comment: Yes, is there a way to pick which child entries I want to hide?

Answer (score 2):

The way I usually accomplish this is to add a "Hide From Nav" Lightswitch field to the sections I want to filter.

This will filter out any entries where the Lightswitch is "on".

```
{% set subnav = craft.entries.descendantOf(mainEntry).hideFromNav('not 1').level(2) %}
```